# Is there any idiom for requesting?

Tags: idioms, idiom-request

In our language we use an idiom If we want to request someone for doing something. And literal translation of that idiom into English would be "**Put your hands together before someone**"(put hands together to make a request), but in English it means Clapping for someone. Is there any idiom which means "Request someone"?

Comment: Please elaborate on what "request someone" means. Request their presence? Request their services?

Comment: As you already know, *[You] put your hands together [**for someone**]* is an idiomatic usage meaning ***applaud*** (Anglophones don't usually use this expression in allusion to ***prayer***, which is presumably how it works in your language). For a "body-based" metaphor evocative of requests/pleading, consider ***get down on one's knees*** (an extreme "supplication" posture).

Comment: Does the phrase "put your hands together before someone" mean "to ask", "to beseech", "to implore"? Would you put your hands together before someone to request that they hand you a pencil, or must the request be more serious and important?

Comment: We do have an idiom **to go (to someone) on bended knee**. It means to act as a supplicant.

Comment: I think OP believes "put your hands together for [someone]" is used as an encouragement (applause indicating an inducement to make that person appear).

Comment: To beg on bended knee

Answer (score 2):

You can go *cap in hand* to someone, if you're humbly asking them for something.

Comment: If you're going to vote an answer down, you owe it to the person who answered to at least let them know why, so they can learn.